# Module is disabled & uninstalled but still shows up in disabled list

Tags: uninstall-module

The extension was not installed with composer

I deleted the files from app/code

I disabled the module
bin/magento module:disable module_name

I uninstalled it
bin/magento module:uninstall -r -c module_name

I am in developer mode, but I still ran
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

and flushed the cache

I also removed / drop table in the database and made sure it doesn't show up in setup_module in the database.

but when I run
php bin/magento module:status
it still shows up in the disabled module list. How do I get rid of it?

**Update:**
I deleted the module out of the app/etc/config.php

I ran php bin/magento setup:updrade

and now its as if I didn't uninstall anything.
It's back in the database everywhere, it is enabled and the config.php file has the entry back in it.

Where is the instruction to do this coming from?

**Update:**
As recommended I removed it from the magento core folder or vendor folder.

That caused an error so I had to run this command to fix it:
composer dumpautoload

Answer (score -1):

open your `magentoRootDirecotry/app/etc/config.php` file and find your module there, just remove it and it's gone! I don't think it would harm anything but if it does please mention in comments.

Comment: Thanks for that it is gone. I have a new problem now though. if I run setup:upgrade it re-installs the module into the database!

Comment: It looks like the module is now in the enabled list, I have no idea how that happened! Is it because I ran setup:upgrade?

Comment: remove the module from the core folder of your Magento. Every time you run setup:upgrade command, it will reinstall all the modules from core folder unless they are disabled or removed from that folder.